# Filter high-frequency PWM but keep low-frequency modulation

Tags: pwm, filter

I have a simple circuit that drive a LED:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSAI7x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input PWM is created as follow:

- base frequency: 200 kHz
- PWM duty-cycle: 0..100% (to change light intensity)
- low freq modulation: 10 Hz..10 kHz

I mean, the low frequency modulation turn on and off the PWM signal.
I'm looking for a way to filter out the 200 kHz base frequency, leaving the low frequency modulation there.

In other works, the PWM duty-cycle should be "levelled" ( = filtered) to obtain a constant DC voltage to drive the LED when it's active. I tried to put a capacitor in parallel to the led but I don't know if it's the best place to put it.

Increasing the capacity will filter a bit the 200 kHz but also "levels-out" the low-frequency modulation.

Is that position the best one?
Is the x20 PWM base frequency enough to easily filter that and only that?

Comment: Start over with specs.  What is your LED power and voltage? What is your best matching supply spec? What control input-output limits or specs? duty cycle vs power,  Show the specs 1st not the fuzzy questions and arbitrary R values. What efficiency do you expect?  Did you know that choke can store energy and now you have a SMPS current regulator?

Comment: Efficiency is not important. The LED maximum current is 100 mA DC, its Vf is about 2.5V. The R values are *not* arbitrary, are the actual ones I see on the board. +V is 3.3V.

Comment: What LED spec? what board?

Comment: Right now is a white one, but it might change (and the R will change according to that). Would you mind to explain me why the color of the LED is important to filter out the 200 kHz PWM frequency?

Comment: Colour affects Vf and 15 ohms * 100mA is 1.5V. Vf for LED >2.8V and Vcc=3.3.  If your values don't make sense , how can we help?

Comment: I'm aware of that. And how Vf affects the filtering?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I didn't say I'm driving it at 100 mA. I said the LED specs are maximum 100 mA.

Comment: You must have specs to design anything well.

Comment: e.g. 0~100% d.c in = 0 to 100mA out @3.1Vmaxdc with AC ripple current < 5%  from 3.3V

Comment: It's all in the schematic: 0..100% PWM (from 0 to 3.3V) modulated as described. Out 53 mA with the current LED that has 2.5 Vf and R = 15 ohm. AC ripple < 5% is ok.

Comment: Then obvious solution is LC filter on source with attenuation ratio of 30dB at PWM f, with Zc(f) < 5% of load, LED ESR which I est,. to be 3 ohms so Zc(f) <= 5% of (3 ohms + 15R) and ZL(f) >= 30x Zc(f)  Does that make sense 2 U?

Comment: Thanks! I will try and write back the results. If you want you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Actually, you would be better with an inductor. Remember LEDs run on current not voltage.

Comment: Trev. you need a cap with that L to make a current filter

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 perhaps, I think this might actually be an X-Y problem. Or the OP does not understand how to dim LEDs.

Comment: He has excess PWM ripple current on Vcc.  Continuous mode SMPS is best.

Answer (score 1):

Establish a low-pass=filter at 10% of the chopping frequency. Thus 20KHz.

A filter at 20KHz has TAU of 1/(2*PI*20KHx) or 50,000 microseconds/2*PI = 9 uSeconds.

You already have the R at 15 ohms. Simply place a 0.47uF cap from FET output to ground. Or any larger cap. This forms a parallel RC low pass filter.